# Package table1: how to select and format summary statistics?

Tags: r, summary

I've produced this table using the `table1` package:

[image: Table]

I would like to remove the median and mean rows, in order to keep just the missing values row. How can I do this?

This is the code I have used:

```
library(table1)
table <- table1(~ unfedprcnt + stuntPerc5 | Country, data = sdg2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `render.continuous` argument which is a function to choose and format the statistics calculated by `table1` (for continuous variables). Example, showing total count and missing:

```
table1(~ unfedprcnt + stuntPerc5 | Country,
       data = sdg2,
       ## select (and format) desired stats:
       render.continuous = function(x){
         with(stats.default(x),
           sprintf("missing: %.0f (%.2f %%)",
                   NMISS,
                   100 * NMISS/N
                  )
         )}
       ## ---------------------------------
       )
```

list default stats available:

```
stats.default(1) |> names()
```

see `?sprintf` to see how to include and format variables in a string